# rand() between 0 and 1

Tags: c++, random

So the following code makes 0 < r < 1

```
r = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX))
```

Why does having  `r = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1))` make -1 < r < 0?

Shouldn't adding one to RAND_MAX make 1 < r < 2?

Edit: I was getting a  warning: integer overflow in expression

on that line, so that might be the problem. I just did `cout << r << endl` and it definitely gives me values between -1 and 0

Comment: Try adding `1` after the last `)`

Comment: Note you should use [uniform_real_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) anyway for this. If you don't have C++11, use the [boost version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/random/uniform_real_distribution.html).

Comment: Algebra error.  If `r` is a random number in the range from zero to `m`, then the ratio `r/m` will be in the range `(0,1)`, but `r/(m+1)` will be in the range `(0, m/(m+1))` NOT the range `(1,2)`.  If `m` is a very large (compared to one), then `m/(m+1)` is approximately one, so your expression `r = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1))` would give a random number approximately in the range (0,1) - that is, if there were no overflow.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

This is entirely **implementation specific**, but it appears that in the C++ environment you're working in, `RAND_MAX` is equal to `INT_MAX`.

Because of this, `RAND_MAX + 1` exhibits undefined (overflow) behavior, and becomes `INT_MIN`. While your initial statement was dividing (random # between 0 and `INT_MAX`)/(`INT_MAX`) and generating a value `0 <= r < 1`, now it's dividing (random # between 0 and `INT_MAX`)/(`INT_MIN`), generating a value `-1 < r <= 0`

In order to generate a random number `1 <= r < 2`, you would want

```
r = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX)) + 1
```

Comment: Why do you put brackets around `RAND_MAX` ?

Comment: @ssc To emphasize the difference from the OP's code. There is no technical reason for those brackets.

Comment: The OP's reasoning for trying it was wrong, but had this been necessary, the UB could've been avoided by adding `1.0` instead of 1, which would coerce `RAND_MAX` to `double` type and so avoid the integer overflow.

Comment: @ssc Because it is macro. You should do it always with macros, unless you know exactly how it is defined. Consider such a definition #define RAND_MAX 1+100  what would the result of the expression above be? ;-)

Comment: @MadPhysicist unless you know exactly, the macro is not an expression but a single number.

Comment: r = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX)) + 0.5;
Round with 0.5 instead of the +1 because no matter what you will be 1 UNLESS you happen to rand() RAND_MAX in which case it will be 2.  This will generate a 0 or 1 and then you can add 1 to that.  Figured the 0 or 1 random value would be good for a digital pin value during testing with a debugger.  Otherwise, nice solve!

Answer (score 41):

`rand() / double(RAND_MAX)` generates a floating-point random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (**inclusive**), but it's not a good way for the following reasons (because RAND_MAX is usually 32767):

1. The number of different random numbers that can be generated is too small: 32768. If you need more different random numbers, you need a different way (a code example is given below)
2. The generated numbers are too coarse-grained: you can get 1/32768, 2/32768, 3/32768, but never anything in between.
3. Limited states of random number generator engine: after generating RAND_MAX random numbers, implementations usually start to repeat the same sequence of random numbers.

Due to the above limitations of rand(), a better choice for generation of random numbers between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (**exclusive**) would be the following snippet (similar to the example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937_64 rng;
    // initialize the random number generator with time-dependent seed
    uint64_t timeSeed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::seed_seq ss{uint32_t(timeSeed & 0xffffffff), uint32_t(timeSeed>>32)};
    rng.seed(ss);
    // initialize a uniform distribution between 0 and 1
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(0, 1);
    // ready to generate random numbers
    const int nSimulations = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < nSimulations; i++)
    {
        double currentRandomNumber = unif(rng);
        std::cout << currentRandomNumber << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is easy to modify to generate random numbers between 1 (inclusive) and 2 (exclusive) by replacing `unif(0, 1)` with `unif(1, 2)`.

Comment: Good heavens.  I've been trying to figure out a zero-to-one random number generator to use in a while loop and this might actually work.  I tried `random_device` each and every way possible, but got the same output.  I have no idea what 0xfffffffff is (hex code?) and the right shift to 32...both are way over my head. (I'm newish to C++, but it's a lot easier than Rust, IMHO.)  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 18):

No, because RAND_MAX is typically expanded to MAX_INT. So adding one (apparently) puts it at MIN_INT (although it should be undefined behavior as I'm told), hence the reversal of sign.

To get what you want you will need to move the +1 outside the computation:

```
r = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX)) + 1;
```

Comment: Adding one *may* put it at MIN_INT, but it's still UB.

Comment: Adding one leads to undefined behavior, as all overflows. This is wrong and misleading, because it appears to work. Either correct your answer or remove it.

Comment: I agree, I've edited accordingly. This however seems to be the observed behavior.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Just to clarify, only for signed overflow.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't. It makes `0 <= r < 1`, but your original is `0 <= r <= 1`.

Note that this can lead to **undefined behavior** if `RAND_MAX + 1` overflows.

Comment: RAND_MAX can't overflow an unsigned type, so you can cast it to unsigned

Answer (score 3):

This is the right way:

```
double randd() {
  return (double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1);
}
```

or

```
double randd() {
  return (double)rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);
}
```

Comment: This fixes the signed integer overflow UB while leaving the rest of the OP's semantics intact, but by reading the description of what they were really trying to do, we can clearly see it still doesn't produce the desired results, as they were wrong to put the addition in that location.

Comment: Why the +1? Let's say RAND_MAX=2, so rand() return 0 or 1 or 2 if you want it to return a number between 0 and 1 shouldn't you divide it by 2 instead of 3?

Comment: 0 is inclusive, and 1 is exclusive. If 1 is inclusive, 1's probability is very small.

Comment: This works for me with g++. (gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6). easy and not too complicated for testprograms.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that `RAND_MAX` is equal to `INT_MAX` and so you're overflowing it to a negative.

Just do this:

```
r = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX)) + 1;
```

Or even better, use C++11's random number generators.

Comment: As you were careful to [point out on someone else's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878965/rand-between-0-and-1#comment12599217_9879003), "overflowing it to a negative" is just what happened in OP's observed case and is not a reliable description, as the overflow is UB and so the resulting program may do anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

`this->value = rand() % (this->max + 1);`

Seems to work fine between 0 and 1++.