# C++ Random Number 1,0 Not Working

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to put either an X or an O in an array.  It doesn't seem to work, however.  It says, "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'row1' was corrupted."

```
char row1[19];
char row2[19];
char row3[19];
char row4[19];

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int r = int(((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX)) + 1);

    if (r == 0)
    {
        row1[i] = 'X';
    }
    else
    {
        row1[i] = 'O';
    }

}

cout << row1[0] << endl;
```

How can I generate a random X or O?  Thank you.

Comment: Not 20, but 19 in `for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)`.

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't it be less than 20 (which is 19)?  You're code is the solution, and does work, I am just wondering.

Comment: Not if your array has 19 elements, which `char row1[19]` will create.

Comment: @user1477388 the valid indices for `int array[n];` are 0 to `n-1`.

Comment: I just leave it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering

Comment: I thought that it would actually give me 20 rows, 0 - 19.  So, `i < 20` would give me 20 rows as well, when `i = 0`.  Right?

Comment: Unrelated, `r` will never be 0, and very rarely be 2, almost always 1, perhaps you intended to divide by `RAND_MAX + 1.0`?

Comment: I got the code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878965/c-rand-between-0-and-1.  Is there a better way?  Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: No you're thinking too hard, `row1[19]` gives you 19.

Comment: So, if it gives me 19, then it is numbered 1 - 19.  But zero counts here, so it actually gives me 20.  You're saying this is not the case?  Sorry for being difficult...

Comment: Nevermind, I see from totymedli's comment, that it doesn't number to 19, just 18.  Thank you.

Comment: @user1477388 Declaring an array `row1[19]` creates an array of 19 elements. These are accessible at indices 0 - 18. What you put in the brackets in array declaration is the *number of elements* of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As elmigranto stated: your loop is incorrect. It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
```

That is because `char row4[19];` is an array that contains 19 elements. The first element is `row4[0]` and the last is `row4[18]` because the numbering is starts from 0. So in the last loop `row[19]` will cause an error.

Comment: Ahh, I see now.  It just numbers to 18, not 19.  I usually don't feel stupid after asking questions, but this one makes me feel dumb...

Answer (score 1):

If you want a coin flipping, you could do something like

```
char row1[20];
char row2[20];
char row3[20];
char row4[20];

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int r = rand() % 2;

    if (r == 0)
    {
        row1[i] = 'X';
    }
    else
    {
        row1[i] = 'O';
    }

}
```

although I have no idea what row2 - row4 are for in your code. The stack corruption occurs with row1[19], since you specified 19 elements only, but 0..19 means 20 elements needed.

Comment: Thanks, that's so simple, and something I've done before.  I didn't think to apply it here.  Good call.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int arr_size = 19;
char row1[arr_size];

for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i) {
    row1[i] = rand() % 2 ? 'O' : 'X';
}
```