# Random.org True random c++

Tags: c++, random

Before anyone yells "check the forums" for duplicate answers I did try and I couldn't find any.

I am trying to make a dice rolling console application in C++ and I need to implement true random numbers (yes true not pseudo) which is proving to be fairly difficult...as I am sure my lecturer intended.

I have heard that Random.org has a c++ library but the only link that I can find is broken and I cant seem to find any documentation on it.

I am trying to allow the user to select a dice from 4, 6, 8 10 and 20 sided dice and roll 1-100 of the selected die.  The results are then displayed.

Does anyone know how I can access random numbers between x-y from random.org or something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: nothing is truly random in a finite system.

Comment: Why is the true random numbers request so strict? If you're going to do a simulation most of the time you can manage to have decent results using pseudo-random, have you explored any of the techniques without a satisfactory result?

Comment: Why do you want to use random.org? A decently seeded crypto PRNG is almost always a better choice.

Comment: I have checked out the LFSR idea and it seems like that might be ok, but the wording in the specification document says "true random" and i know a lot of people have used random.org in the past for this assignment

Comment: @DanielA.White The [laws of physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_indeterminacy) disagree with you.

Comment: On Unix systems, there's usually `/dev/random`.  But it can become very slow after a dozen or so values---I'd recommend it for getting the seed, then use a high quality PRNG for the actual values.

Comment: Hope this helps:
          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878965/c-rand-between-0-and-1

Comment: @DanielA.White No offense, but "true randomness" has absolutely nothing to do with *finiteness* of your space, but rather with *determism* of the laws that rule your space. Example: an electron orbiting around a nucleus has finite possible states, but a measure of its quantum state would give you a purely random result (weighted by the probability given by the quantum state). The computer of the OP most likely lies in our physical space, which appears to be quantic according to state-of-the-art research. Hence, true random *is* possible (e.g.: 50th digit of the temperature of the CPU).

Comment: @Boris: The 4th digit is random. The 10th digit varies across the chip. The 50th digit doesn't even exist in a physically meaningful way.

Comment: @MSalters good point :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL in the link to the C++ library on the [Random.org HTTP Client Archive](http://www.random.org/clients/http/archive/) page is malformed. It's supposed to point to [doughague/random-dot-org](https://github.com/doughague/random-dot-org) on GitHub.  You can use that to access real random number data generated via atmospheric noise.

Comment: Thanks!  And before I spend a long time reading through it and working out how to make it do exactly what I want i was wondering if there was a tutorial that explains how to use the library exactly?  If not no problem :)

Comment: @tim I don't see any tutorials, but there are a couple of examples linked in the README.md file.